# How to config Sequelize ORM to execute serialized queries

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron, sequelize.js

I'm working on an electron app which executes write queries like - insert, delete, update etc. concurrently. I'm using SQLite which is single threat database, So if the app fires multiple write queries concurrently, the SQLite database is showing error that `Database is locked`. So How can I config the sequelize to execute  serialized queries?

```js
const { app } = require('electron')
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize')
const path = require('path')
const cls = require('cls-hooked')

const namespace = cls.createNamespace('P&C.Beejak')
Sequelize.useCLS(namespace)

const db = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    storage: path.join(app.getPath('userData') + '/database', 'database.db'),
})

module.exports = db
```

Answer (score 0):

Use transactions w/ the correct isolation method: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/transactions.html

```
// You can overwrite the isolationLevel setting globally with an option in the Sequelize constructor:


const { Sequelize, Transaction } = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite::memory:', {
  isolationLevel: Transaction.ISOLATION_LEVELS.SERIALIZABLE
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still database is locking when concurrent write queries executes.